# Cant start laravel 5.6 on Ubuntu server with NGINX

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, laravel-5.6

I try to install Laravel 5.6 on my production server but I have this error :

> [error] 12364#12364: *6 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP
>   Warning:  require(/var/www/laravel/public/../vendor/autoload.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /var/www/laravel/public/index.php on line 24 PHP message: PHP Fatal
>   error:  require(): Failed opening required
>   '/var/www/laravel/public/../vendor/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/laravel/public/index.php
>   on line 24" while reading response header from upstream

Server os is Ubuntu 16.04 x64

Comment: It shows that your webserver is pointed to the `/var/www/laravel/` directory. I think it shold be `/var/www/html/laravel/` And try to run `composer install` and `composer update`

Comment: I change the directory to `/var/www/laravel` so this is not the case!

Comment: Dammm I need php 7.1.3 on my server for laravel 5.6

Comment: `compose update `

Comment: Yes, you need to have `php >= 7` version to use `laravel > 5.4` so if you use laravel 5.6 then you need to have `php 7.1.3` or higher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using `Laravel 5.6` you need to have `php version 7.1.3` or higher. Try to install `php >= 7.1.3`

After the installation try to run

```
composer update
```

See more in this [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/upgrade)!

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

I need to update PHP version to 7.1.3

https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-and-configure-php-70-or-php-71-on-ubuntu-16-04

or this will help:

https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/install-php-7-1-with-nginx-on-an-ubuntu-16-04-vps/